# My ajax code doesnt output JSON file

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, widget

So ive been trying to get this to work for hours now but im just stuck.

I have a simple guestbook page setup and I have this code creating a JSON file:

```
<?php
/* Konstanter för db-inställningar */
define("DBHOST", "localhost");
define("DBUSER", "guestbook");
define("DBPASS", "password");
define("DBDATABASE", "guestbook");

/* DB-anslutning */
$db = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBDATABASE) or die('Fel vid anslutning');


$numrows = 999; // Maxvärde
if(isset($_GET['numrows'])) {
    $numrows = intval($_GET['numrows']);
}


/* SQL-fråga */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $numrows";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die('Fel vid SQL-fråga');

/* Loopa genom resultet och spara till ny array */
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

echo $json;
```

This outputs it in JSON format and then I have this code trying to read the file and output the content of the JSON to this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Guestbook</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilmall.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" type="text/css">
<body>

<nav id="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Administration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="webservice.php">JSON</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ajax.htm">Webbservice</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

<div class="posts">

<h2>WebService</h2>


<div id="info"></div>



<script>


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// läs ut svar

xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);

        var jsonStr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        var users= jsonStr.posts;

        for(var i=0; i<users.lenght; i++) {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
};

xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/webbutveckling2/moment3/webservice.php",true);
xhr.send(null);

</script>










</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I cannot for the love of good see what im doing wrong.

I need this to output the JSON content, also I would like to just output the 3 latest entried from the JSON file only.

What im doing wrong?

Edit:

Here is the JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Emil1234",
        "post": "My name is Emil and this is a test for a post on the guestbook wall",
        "postdate": "2018-03-15 16:41:10"
    },
    {
        "id": "22",
        "name": "golddigger",
        "post": "Hi! This is my first visit to this epic guestbook",
        "postdate": "2018-03-25 14:52:11"
    },
    {
        "id": "23",
        "name": "Tester123",
        "post": "Im just doing another test dont mind me",
        "postdate": "2018-03-25 14:52:31"
    },
    {
        "id": "24",
        "name": "the bluff",
        "post": "Whatsup all",
        "postdate": "2018-03-25 15:17:17"
    }
]
```

When I update my code in the js to the following:

```
<script>


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// läs ut svar

xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
</script>
```

It does put out the raw information in the following way:

[image: The output]

How do I output this to be show just the latest 3 posts?

Edit 2:

```
<script>


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// läs ut svar

xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

        //var jsonStr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = users[i].name + " - " + users[i].post + " - " + users[i].postdate ;     }
    }
};

xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/webbutveckling2/moment3/webservice.php?numrows=3",true);
xhr.send(null);

</script>
```

This outputs just one, is my url wrong?

Outputs the following:
[image: Output]

Comment: Any errors in your dev console? Is the actual response 'correct' found under the network tab of the dev tools? Can you paste an example of the json output (add to your question)?

Comment: Json output added to the question. There have to be something wrong with my for loop, I want to display the content by only showing the last 3 entries.

Comment: It looks like its doing a limit of 999 since you are not actually passing the GET var of numrows in your xhr call.

Comment: I do see where something could go wrong in the js: `var users= jsonStr.posts;` ... you should be getting a console error that `posts is undefined of object jsonStr`. Because there is no `posts` value in the json. You should also name `jsonStr` to `jsonObj` because its not a string anymore ;) it was turned into an object by JSON.parse. Yes I'm nitpicky.

Comment: Ok, I found out some new information, please read what I added in the question under edit, after the Json picture. How do I make that to output the last 3 posts only?

Answer (score 0):

There is not " numrows " is going as a get request in the ajax call thatsand just try putting the fetch function in a while loop and concatenate in the output variable

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Im little confused, how would I go around doing this? Im having a bit of an issue understanding your answer :P
I posted an update on the question just as you posted this, did you read my edit?

Comment: If you want to show the latest 3 post them add created_at time column in the db table and in sql query make it orderby created_at and limit 3 . Hope it will work

Comment: And as i mentioned earlier you got nomrows missing in the link change it to http://localhost/webbutveckling2/moment3/webservice.php?numrows=3